# Manually add confidence intervals to barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have to following dataframe with confidence intervals "ci_min" and ci_max" for each mean of species "x" and "y". How can I manually add confidence intervals on the barplots?

```
data <- data.frame("sp" = c("x","y"), count = c(-4.011, 2.45), "ci_min" = c(-4.2,1.68), "ci_max" = c(-4.01, 3.28))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = sp, y = counts, fill = sp)) +
    stat_summary(geom="bar", fun.y=mean, position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add error bars with `geom_errobar` by specifying `ymin` and `ymax` in main `ggplot2` call.

```
ggplot(data, aes(sp, count, ymin = ci_min, ymax = ci_max, fill = sp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_errorbar()
```

[image]